# Filter per output in multiple hosts in output plugin logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I would like to send logs to multiple hosts in the output plugin of logstash. Is there a way I can filter logs for each output separately using the filter plugin?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can, you need to use conditionals based on some information present on one or more of your fields, this is described in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I add the output plugin inside the filter plugin?

Comment: You can't, logstash has three main blocks, the `input`, the `filter` and the `output`, you can only use output plugins inside the `output` block. Why would you want to use an `output` plugin inside the `filter` block? There is no reason for it.

Comment: @Charith sattiva have you had success with my answer/suggested approach? If yes, I would really appreciate if you would accept/upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send events to multiple or different elasticsearch host based on some criteria.

You would do it the following way:

**Sample pipeline**

```
input{
  # some input plugin, e.g. "beats"
}

filter{
  # some filter(s), e.g. "mutate", "grok", "date"
}

output{
  # send event to an elasticsearch host based on the value of field "foo"
  if [foo] == "bar"{
    elasticsearch{
      hosts => ["http://bar.com:9200"]
      ...
    }
  }
  else if [foo] == "bazz"{
    elasticsearch{
      hosts => ["http://bazz.com:9200"]
      ...
    }
  }
  else{
    elasticsearch{
      hosts => ["http://foo.bar.bazz.com:9200"]
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I hope I could help you!